# How could I concentrate heat to go through a piece of glass and burn somethng on the other end of the glass?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know its a long question but there is a reason I am trying to get this done. I have items that have a protective layer of glass covering the warranty sticker. I want to burn part of the warranty sticker thats behind the protective glass to show the item is no longer under warranty. 
Any ideas what I can use to focus heat to transfer enough heat through the glass to burn the sticker? I need to concentrate the heat as the burn only needs to be about 5mm by 10mm and dont want to heat more than that surface area.

Regards

Comment: How about using a convex lens and sunlight? Is there a reason you can't disassemble or heat from behind, or just put an "out of warranty" sticker somewhere?

Comment: As an aside, if it's covered with glass, where would the ashes & smoke go?

Comment: Try the ideas as an experiment and tell us what happened please. I am very interested to know the results.

Comment: Not heat, _light_.  Light gets converted to heat when it is _absorbed_ by something.  I don't know what kind of glass you are dealing with, but ordinary window glass transmits visible light and near-infrared light without absorbing it.  That will allow the label behind the glass to absorb the light instead.

Answer (score 1):

A dangerous but feasible idea is to buy a 500mW visible light laser. Or maybe a simple magnifying glass and some sunlight would be better.